# How to install gcc 4.7.3 on CentOS?

Tags: linux, gcc, dockerfile

I want to install gcc 4.7.3 on centos, but I use yum search gcc like that:

```
yum search gcc
```

it show me too many information to choose:

```
gcc-c++.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
gcc-gnat.x86_64 : Ada 95 support for GCC
gcc-objc.x86_64 : Objective-C support for GCC
gcc-objc++.x86_64 : Objective-C++ support for GCC
gcc-plugin-devel.x86_64 : Support for compiling GCC plugins
libgcc.i686 : GCC version 4.8 shared support library
libgcc.x86_64 : GCC version 4.8 shared support library
relaxngcc-javadoc.noarch : Javadoc for relaxngcc
compat-gcc-44.x86_64 : Compatibility GNU Compiler Collection
compat-gcc-44-c++.x86_64 : C++ support for compatibility compiler
```

I don't know which one is gcc 4.7.3. I want to write install to Dokcerfile, please tell me how to install it in simple way. just using command via Terminal
Then,I using the command:

```
yum instal gcc-4.7.3
```

It show :

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.neu.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror.neu.edu.cn
 * updates: mirror.neu.edu.cn
No package gcc-4.7.3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: check this out:
http://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Comment: Does it just said how to install 4.7.2? But I need to install 4.7.3,and I using yum install gcc, it install 4.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to get 4.7.3 with devtools, instead, the `devtools` package would install you a gcc version 4.7.2.

`devtoolset-1.1` package contains `gcc-4.7.2`

Follow the below commands to install devtoolset.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/devtools-1.1.repo
yum --enablerepo=testing-1.1-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.1-gcc devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++
```

gcc is located in `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.0/root/usr/bin/` and so you will have to update `$PATH`

```
export PATH=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.0/root/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

Now the gcc version should be version 4.7.2

You can check it using `gcc -v` command.

NOTE: There is an option for you download the source and build to get the latest changes in the devtoolset package.